# Katalon Studio - Can I reuse an old activation code?

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-studio

I have been using version 6.3.2 which I enabled using the offline activation code.  I have since moved to a new desk with a new workstation.  I was able to install version 6.3 but since offline activation is no longer available it is useless.

I'm not trying to use Version 7 which requires a license, I simply want to use a version that has always been free.  Online activation is not an option .

Does anyone know if there is a way to get the old offline activation code off another machine and reuse on a new install?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you cannot use the old offline activation code, because you moved to a new workstation and the offline license is [bonded to the physical machine](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/activate-KSE.html#offline-activation).

You probably have to contact Katalon support to see if they can activate an offline license for you for the new machine, or activate a new one yourself.